# 20 second Vimeo API calls with WordPress integration

Tags: wordpress, vimeo, vimeo-api

We have a WordPress custom build and have integrated the Vimeo API to pull videos through to the website.

The setup is working but the API calls are taking 20 seconds. We have tested using Postman and they only take 1-2 seconds.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `fields` parameter on your requests to tell the API to only return the metadata needed for your application. Because Vimeo API responses can be quite large, especially when retrieving a list of videos, the `fields` parameter can significantly reduce the size of the response, and subsequently increase response time.

For example, let's say you're making a request to get the last 10 videos you uploaded. The request would look like this:

```
curl -X GET https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos?page=1&per_page=10
  -H 'Accept: application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4' 
  -H 'Authorization: bearer [token]'
```

The response would return the full and complete video objects for 10 videos, which can be quite large. However if you only need some of the metadata in the response, such as the video's name, description, and its link on vimeo.com, then the same request with the `fields` param will look like this:

```
curl -X GET https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos?page=1&per_page=10&fields=uri,name,description,link
  -H 'Accept: application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4' 
  -H 'Authorization: bearer [token]'
```

The `fields` parameter is documented here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/common-formats#json-filter

Comment: This is helpful but we have tried and it makes no difference. Is there a way to identify whether its the server our website is on or the Vimeo server?